# How do I save session data for the anonymous users?

Tags: 7, sessions

In my last project for Drupal 6, I did save the data using code similar to the following one:

```
$_SESSION['xxx'] = serialize($data);
```

In Drupal 7, it doesn't work.

How should I save the session data for the anonymous users, in Drupal 7?

Answer (score 4):

It because drupal save session with key, this mean you should do something like

```
  $_SESSION['yourkey']['xxx'] = serialize($data);
```

You can try this.

```
function lists_session($key, $value = NULL) {
  global $user;

  static $storage;

  // If the user is anonymous, force a session start.
  if(!user->uid) {
    drupal_session_start();
  }

  if ($value) {
    $storage[$key] = $value;
    $_SESSION['lists'][$key] = $value;   // I use 'lists' in case some other module uses 'type' in $_SESSION
  }
  else if (empty($storage[$key]) && isset($_SESSION['lists'][$key])) {
    $storage[$key] = $_SESSION['lists'][$key];
  }
  return $storage[$key];
}
```

So, to save a variable in Session:

```
lists_session("xxx", serialize($data));
```

And to retrieve the value, just use:

```
$myVar = lists_session("xxx");
```

and aslo as MOLOT mentions sometimes session not stareted for anonymous users then you should `drupal_session_start()` manually.

Answer (score 2):

[According to the docs](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--session.inc/7), that is all you should need to do.

Which means that there is either a bug, or your pages are being cached for anon users so the session data is not being read. I would check your caching settings in the first instance.

Comment: thanks. Perhaps this is a bug. but until I decided to use it [session_api](http://drupal.org/project/session_api)

Comment: @vitaly.batonov can you elaborate on how you used session_api to resolve your issue?

Answer (score 2):

Drupal 7 sometimes does not automatically start sessions for anonymous users. To use sessions for them, you may need to force session started with [drupal_session_start](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!session.inc/function/drupal_session_start/7) to be able to use `$_SESSION`.

Comment: Is there a way to tell Drupal, ALWAYS start a session for anonymous users?

Answer (score 1):

After you saving data by following:

```
$_SESSION['xxx'] = serialize($data);
```

Need another function:

```
drupal_session_start();
```

Due to the Session table needs a record with id=0, you could manually insert a record with id=0.

Answer (score 0):

create a user with uid=0 in users table
because drupal  always uses that uid for anonymous users