# How to call hook in template.php after login from any user in drupal 7?

Tags: theming, hooks

I am using below code to get the user login gender information & store in SESSION, I want to call below code after login, I already try this hook `function bartik_user_login(&$edit, $account) {}`but its not working. Please help. Thanks

```
if (user_is_logged_in())
{    
global $user;
    $uid = user_load($user->uid);
    $profile_main = profile2_load_by_user($uid, 'main');
    $field_iam = field_get_items('profile2',$profile_main,'field_i_am_field');
    $_SESSION['i_am']=$field_iam[0][value];
    echo $_SESSION['i_am'];
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use preprocess function. For example -

```
function yourtheme_preprocess_user_login(&$vars) {
  $vars['intro_text'] = t('This is my awesome login form');
}
```

The general flow is:

theme($hook, $var) >> preprocess functions >> process functions >> finally either goto template.php or call theme function >> return output as string

therefore, template.php or theme function call is the final destination, no hook runs after template.php

Comment: take care that yourtheme should be replaced with your theme name. Your code will set the seesion variable. Use that session variable where ever you want. It will be set. Also any change in template.php file needs clearing the cache.

Comment: Thanks @Parvind.. Actually due to some silly mistake I was facing problem

Answer (score 2):

You should use this hook in a custom module. You should also not tamper with core code as the Bartik theme directly. Also take a look at this:

[How do I save session data for the anonymous users?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/4851/how-do-i-save-session-data-for-the-anonymous-users)

Comment: If I don't want to use custom module then is there any easy way through which am I put this code @Wtoser

Comment: @samzha This hook needs to be implemented in a module, you can't implement it anywhere else (unless you change how core works)